# Fastest way to call function multiple times with delay

Tags: javascript, loops

What is the fastest way to execute a function infinite times asynchronously?

I thought about 2 ways to do it.

**Using interval**

```
setInterval(function(){
   // do stuff
})
```

**Using while**

```
setTimeout(function(){
   while(true) {
      // do stuff
   }
})
```

How should I handle this to get the fastest results possible?
I don't care about the time it takes to start the loop. I just care about the time it takes to do a loop.

Comment: With `requestAnimationFrame`?

Comment: @elclanrs - that answers an entirely different question.  @Afonso - Your timeout+while loop isn't async except for the first call.  Put a `setTimeout( thisFn )` call _inside_ the function

Comment: You should implement several different approaches and measure the time for each one.

Comment: Strictly speaking, omitting the second argument to either `setInterval` or `setTimeout` is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function foo(){
    // do stuff
    setTimeout( foo, 0 );
}

foo();
```

`setInterval` has the possibility to queue up hundreds or thousands of calls to your function if they take longer than the interval time to run, effectively blocking.  Your while loop isn't async, except for the first call.

Comment: Well, your example is not async when it first runs. But the main idea is here. Thank you :)

Comment: Browsers no longer seem prone to stacking and there is no "blocking queue up": http://jsfiddle.net/gomq31gr/

Answer (score 1):

The second way will be fastest. It only needs to go to the event queue once, then it stays in the infinite loop.

This will run one function asynchronously, then it will block the UI while it's running. If that's not what you wanted, then this answer isn't helpful. But I assumed that both of your methods did what you want, and you just wanted the version that loops quickest.

Comment: I meant the one with `while`, I mistyped "first".

Comment: 2nd one isn't async (except for the first call)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, then.

Comment: @zyklus I'm just answering the question about which is fastest. He's the one who wrote the code, I assume it does what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

When *properly coded*, both setInterval and setTimeout will have the same "fastest" approach<sup>1</sup>.

However, the example with the loop is *wrong* in a comparative context and will freeze the browser (as the loop is no longer an asynchronous construct). It should instead be written to invoke setTimout again, as shown:

```
setTimeout(function fn () {   
   setTimeout(fn, 0);        // loop is implicit with scheduling next timeout
   code();
}, 0);
```

Which is now *equivalent* to:

```
setInterval(function () { code() }, 0);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> While it *may* have made a difference in the past it [No Longer Matters](http://jsfiddle.net/dagshwjv/1) - both approaches have the same lower-bound on how fast they will invoke the callback and schedule the next event, which is a minimum of ~4-5ms in a desktop browser on Windows.

Since this is a fixed lower bound it is often worthwhile to *process multiple items* each callback (say "do 20 milliseconds worth of work"), such that the timeout/delay itself does not dominate the overall time. It is also possible to [Run Multiple "Parallel" Timeouts](http://jsfiddle.net/y8bgzxu1/1/) to increase the effective-rate a shared callback is executed; however, such events are not guaranteed to be well-distributed.

Modern browsers are also [*Not* Affected by "setTimeout Stacking"](http://jsfiddle.net/gomq31gr/); thus for running the callback as fast as possible either approach is Just Fine.

As such, use the approach that *best* represents the problem.